# Unable to download image from firebase cloud storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download image from firebase cloud storage and below is my code

```
    StorageReference storageReference =FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference islandRef = storageReference.child("images/img.png");
    

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    islandRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(bytes -> 
            Log.e("KKKKKKK", "success"))
            .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
        Log.e("KKKKKKK", "fail");
        // Handle any errors
    });
```

But I am getting below exception. My image is available on images/img.png

```
StorageException has occurred.
                                                                                                
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                                                                 
Code: -13000 HttpResult: 412

2023-08-19 17:22:00.545 15780-15845 StorageException        com.my.cutter 
E  {  "error": {    "code": 412,    "message": "A required service account is missing necessary permissions. Please resolve by visiting the Storage page of the Firebase Console and re-linking your Firebase bucket or see this FAQ for more info: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#storage-accounts. If you recently made changes to your service account, please wait a few minutes for the changes to propagate through our systems and try again."  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 412,    "message": "A required service account is missing necessary permissions. Please resolve by visiting the Storage page of the Firebase Console and re-linking your Firebase bucket or see this FAQ for more info: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#storage-accounts. If you recently made changes to your service account, please wait a few minutes for the changes to propagate through our systems and try again."  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.LimitedConcurrencyExecutor.lambda$decorate$0$LimitedConcurrencyExecutor(LimitedConcurrencyExecutor.java:65)
        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.-$$Lambda$LimitedConcurrencyExecutor$o0K4kvcMhb2fLsng0w0-4DyAD5U.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.-$$Lambda$CustomThreadFactory$25wFMnJXuxCXflRCTG3ggSOiDOE.run(Unknown Source:4)
```

Comment: The error line states pretty clearly that: A required service account is missing necessary permissions. Please resolve by visiting the Storage page of the Firebase Console and re-linking your Firebase bucket or see this FAQ for more info: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#storage-accounts

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Not resolved even after created new sevice account